# Why did they not wear any mask to conceal their identity?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-old-guard

In the movie, *The Old Guard*, Charlize Theron is very cautious about having her picture taken by accident by tourists. She offers to take a picture for the tourists and deletes the picture with herself in it.

But during their mission in South Sudan, none of the four operators is wearing any masks. Why do they have this sudden 180 degree shift in attitude?

Comment: They have a "no repeats" rule so they wouldn't need masks. They repeated though because Andy has a soft spot for saving kids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## There was no need

They South Sudan mission was not in a well developed part of the world where cameras would be expected to be highly prevalent so wearing masks would be "overkill" and highly suspicious for a covert operation.

Of course, *out of universe*, the "delete the picture" is just exposition to indicate that  they were trying to remain undiscovered as to their true nature and this, in fact, drives the whole plot of the movie.

Comment: Copley's collection included posed Civil War pictures that Andy was in and which she didn't "delete". When did she suddenly get wise to the fear of being recognized?

Comment: @rosends during the civil war photography was basically brand new. Maybe she didn't know any better at the time. Also, that was before the internet.